# How to get the size of a GUI Label?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm developing a game in Unity3D and with it are the GUI codes inside the OnGUI() function. Is there a way to get the size of a GUI Label with GUIStyle [and font] before I can specify its dimensions in the new Rect() parameter? If there's any possible way, I can use it to dynamically change the dimensions of the label depending on some factors like the Screen resolution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use System.Drawing if you work with Unity.
Use http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUIStyle.CalcSize.html instead.
ex :

```
Vector2 size = yourStyle.CalcSize (new GUIContent ("your text"));
```

If you use a style specified in the current skin replace `yourStyle` by `GUI.skin.[...]` (http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUISkin.html).
Then you can use it like this:

```
GUI.Label (new Rect (anchorX, anchorY, size.x, size.y), "your text");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will work in your case but may help get you in the right direction

```
/// <summary>
/// Calculate Render Width
/// </summary>
/// <param name="str"></param>
/// <param name="fontFamily"></param>
/// <param name="fontSize"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static float GetWidthOfString(string str, string fontFamily, int fontSize)
{
    var font = new System.Drawing.Font(fontFamily, fontSize, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    var size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(str, font); // GDI              

    return size.Width;
}
```